# Upload files spring boot application configured with NGINX Load Balancer

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, nginx, file-upload

I have spring boot application which has REST API to upload zip files. The API takes the zip file and extract the content and keep this in the local directory (as the zip contain some jar files and the application dynamically loads these files as and when needed). All this works fine in local as well as in server.
The problem arises when the application is configured with NGINX load balancer. The uploading APIs are not working. Can anyone give some workaround how to implement this? We can not use something like Amazon S3 since our application will run on own servers of clients.

I was thinking if there is a way where all the instances of the application running behind the load balancer will have the same copy of the uploaded zip files.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. 
As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the 
[How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question. Include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to 
reproduce the issue. See also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I need a workaround for a specific scenario. In one line i can say that i want to upload files to a application which resides behind a nginx load balancer

Comment: You didn't provide any specific details of the application or the issue. "not working" is not a description of an issue. Stackoverflow is a Q&A site with very specific guidelines about how to ask. It is not a discussion forum to throw a topic and discuss alternatives. Please read the links I shared above.